# Does an editor with a "multiple versions in a single file" feature exist?

Tags: file, version-control, editor

I'm new to the programming community in general and I'm not sure how I would search for this but, does such an an editor with a feature that allows to save different versions of a code in a single file exist? If yes, what do you call the feature?

Basically I want to look through an entire code file and be able to identify (through highlights? or code folding?) which code snippets has been edited or added in which version. Either that, or be able to switch through each version of the file (listed in order).

This is so I can save and document each code snippet I add or edit, step-by-step, so I can look back at it and easily understand the logic of how I created the code.

Comment: RCS saves all the history of a file in a single ,v file but that is hardly what you want.

Comment: Why would you want the editor to know about your version control anyway? There are excellent bindings for various existing version control back-ends for Emacs, which allow you to browse the history of changes in various ways without burdening the file itself with these annotations (which would make the file format unsuitable for feeding to a compiler or interpreter, anyway). None of the modes I have seen do exactly what you are asking for, but some of them offer a very solid foundation for implementing something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into bindings and version control back-ends.

 If it clarifies anything, the idea I was going for was a "tutorial in a file" where I can save each step per code snippet. I thought this would be a more efficient way to re-learn a complex code after months of not checking it rather than comments.

Comment: Tangentially, sounds like [Literate Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming) could be for you.

Comment: By "bindings" in this context I simply meant what in Emacs parlance is called a "mode"; code to integrate external functionality (and / or provide new features). As a specific term it usually refers to code to provide a library's binary API e.g. to a scripting language. Sorry for the slightly loose terminology.

Comment: O sorry, I didn't mention I just started my first few coding projects after following loads of tutorials so I'm still pretty newbie. So yeah, a lot of technical terms I'm not familiar with but I'll look into it.

To make it more clear, I basically wanted to see my snippets in a file like how a tutorial would show their snippets:
http://dev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-add-your-own-tools-to-unitys-editor--active-10047